# Create object in public class

Tags: java, android

I have such code. But it crushes when I execute it with error

```
unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo blah blah blah
```

No errors before compile. Why I'm unable to create instance of class in that place? When I create it in method - it''s ok. Where I should create this objects?
   This class is the main class in my app. It appears after default "Blank activity" creation

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

EditText cocktail_1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); // why i cant do like that? Why I haven't got any errors? Where I should write this line?
AlertDialog.Builder one_more_error; //but its ok

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

...
}
```

My manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.alexeypolusov.firstlol">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Please do not edit my code

Comment: I don't see where in this code you are trying to instantiate a ComponentInfo class.

Comment: Show us your manifest.

Comment: post a sufficient code please..

Comment: You are initializing EditText before even creating view in activity . It will give you error. You have to ini it into `onCreate` method.Still if you want to write there just declare EditText there. Like `EditText cocktail_1;` and in onCreate Method ini it like `cocktail_1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);` .

Answer (score 0):

You need to init all views in create when Activity was already created.
For example try this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
EditText cocktail_1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
}
}
```